# Scraping a URL host and primary path plus query string to produce a list of all possible additional extensions for that query

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, if-statement

I am working on a project to to scrape table data from a url.

The main web domain is https://www.pro-football-reference.com. I have already written the code to scrape the table data from this domain.

A search for statistical data on this might start with a query with set parameters. For example: here is the url with table data for all players in the National Football League who have thrown at least 25 passes in their careers:

```
input_url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/play-index/psl_finder.cgi?request=1&match=combined&year_min=1920&year_max=2016&season_start=1&season_end=-1&pos%5B%5D=qb&pos%5B%5D=rb&pos%5B%5D=wr&pos%5B%5D=te&pos%5B%5D=e&pos%5B%5D=t&pos%5B%5D=g&pos%5B%5D=c&pos%5B%5D=ol&pos%5B%5D=dt&pos%5B%5D=de&pos%5B%5D=dl&pos%5B%5D=ilb&pos%5B%5D=olb&pos%5B%5D=lb&pos%5B%5D=cb&pos%5B%5D=s&pos%5B%5D=db&pos%5B%5D=k&pos%5B%5D=p&draft_year_min=1936&draft_year_max=2017&draft_slot_min=1&draft_slot_max=500&draft_pick_in_round=pick_overall&conference=any&draft_pos%5B%5D=qb&draft_pos%5B%5D=rb&draft_pos%5B%5D=wr&draft_pos%5B%5D=te&draft_pos%5B%5D=e&draft_pos%5B%5D=t&draft_pos%5B%5D=g&draft_pos%5B%5D=c&draft_pos%5B%5D=ol&draft_pos%5B%5D=dt&draft_pos%5B%5D=de&draft_pos%5B%5D=dl&draft_pos%5B%5D=ilb&draft_pos%5B%5D=olb&draft_pos%5B%5D=lb&draft_pos%5B%5D=cb&draft_pos%5B%5D=s&draft_pos%5B%5D=db&draft_pos%5B%5D=k&draft_pos%5B%5D=p&c1stat=pass_att&c1comp=gt&c1val=25&c5val=1.0&order_by=pass_td'
```

But this url only contains the statistical table data for players 1 - 100 on this list. So there are 7 additional urls with 100 players each and one additional url with 81 players.

The url for the 2nd url from this query contains a table with players 101-200 is here:

```
url_passing2 = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/play-index/psl_finder.cgi?request=1&match=combined&year_min=1920&year_max=2016&season_start=1&season_end=-1&pos%5B%5D=qb&pos%5B%5D=rb&pos%5B%5D=wr&pos%5B%5D=te&pos%5B%5D=e&pos%5B%5D=t&pos%5B%5D=g&pos%5B%5D=c&pos%5B%5D=ol&pos%5B%5D=dt&pos%5B%5D=de&pos%5B%5D=dl&pos%5B%5D=ilb&pos%5B%5D=olb&pos%5B%5D=lb&pos%5B%5D=cb&pos%5B%5D=s&pos%5B%5D=db&pos%5B%5D=k&pos%5B%5D=p&draft_year_min=1936&draft_year_max=2017&draft_slot_min=1&draft_slot_max=500&draft_pick_in_round=pick_overall&conference=any&draft_pos%5B%5D=qb&draft_pos%5B%5D=rb&draft_pos%5B%5D=wr&draft_pos%5B%5D=te&draft_pos%5B%5D=e&draft_pos%5B%5D=t&draft_pos%5B%5D=g&draft_pos%5B%5D=c&draft_pos%5B%5D=ol&draft_pos%5B%5D=dt&draft_pos%5B%5D=de&draft_pos%5B%5D=dl&draft_pos%5B%5D=ilb&draft_pos%5B%5D=olb&draft_pos%5B%5D=lb&draft_pos%5B%5D=cb&draft_pos%5B%5D=s&draft_pos%5B%5D=db&draft_pos%5B%5D=k&draft_pos%5B%5D=p&c1stat=pass_att&c1comp=gt&c1val=25&c5val=1.0&order_by=pass_td&offset=100'
```

Notice that these are exactly the same until the very last part, where there is the additional extension string '&offset=100'. Each additional page has the same host/path/query string plus '&offset=200', '&offset=300', '&offset=400', and so on up to '&offset=800'.

My question is this: starting with a url like this, how can I create a Python function that will collect a list of all of the possible url iterations from this host/path/query string, so that I can get the entire list of players who match this query?

My desired output would be a list that looks something like this:

```
list_or_urls: ['https://www.pro-football-reference.com/play-index/psl_finder.cgi?request=1&match=combined&year_min=1920&year_max=2016&season_start=1&season_end=-1&pos%5B%5D=qb&pos%5B%5D=rb&pos%5B%5D=wr&pos%5B%5D=te&pos%5B%5D=e&pos%5B%5D=t&pos%5B%5D=g&pos%5B%5D=c&pos%5B%5D=ol&pos%5B%5D=dt&pos%5B%5D=de&pos%5B%5D=dl&pos%5B%5D=ilb&pos%5B%5D=olb&pos%5B%5D=lb&pos%5B%5D=cb&pos%5B%5D=s&pos%5B%5D=db&pos%5B%5D=k&pos%5B%5D=p&draft_year_min=1936&draft_year_max=2017&draft_slot_min=1&draft_slot_max=500&draft_pick_in_round=pick_overall&conference=any&draft_pos%5B%5D=qb&draft_pos%5B%5D=rb&draft_pos%5B%5D=wr&draft_pos%5B%5D=te&draft_pos%5B%5D=e&draft_pos%5B%5D=t&draft_pos%5B%5D=g&draft_pos%5B%5D=c&draft_pos%5B%5D=ol&draft_pos%5B%5D=dt&draft_pos%5B%5D=de&draft_pos%5B%5D=dl&draft_pos%5B%5D=ilb&draft_pos%5B%5D=olb&draft_pos%5B%5D=lb&draft_pos%5B%5D=cb&draft_pos%5B%5D=s&draft_pos%5B%5D=db&draft_pos%5B%5D=k&draft_pos%5B%5D=p&c1stat=pass_att&c1comp=gt&c1val=25&c5val=1.0&order_by=pass_td', 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/play-index/psl_finder.cgi?request=1&match=combined&year_min=1920&year_max=2016&season_start=1&season_end=-1&pos%5B%5D=qb&pos%5B%5D=rb&pos%5B%5D=wr&pos%5B%5D=te&pos%5B%5D=e&pos%5B%5D=t&pos%5B%5D=g&pos%5B%5D=c&pos%5B%5D=ol&pos%5B%5D=dt&pos%5B%5D=de&pos%5B%5D=dl&pos%5B%5D=ilb&pos%5B%5D=olb&pos%5B%5D=lb&pos%5B%5D=cb&pos%5B%5D=s&pos%5B%5D=db&pos%5B%5D=k&pos%5B%5D=p&draft_year_min=1936&draft_year_max=2017&draft_slot_min=1&draft_slot_max=500&draft_pick_in_round=pick_overall&conference=any&draft_pos%5B%5D=qb&draft_pos%5B%5D=rb&draft_pos%5B%5D=wr&draft_pos%5B%5D=te&draft_pos%5B%5D=e&draft_pos%5B%5D=t&draft_pos%5B%5D=g&draft_pos%5B%5D=c&draft_pos%5B%5D=ol&draft_pos%5B%5D=dt&draft_pos%5B%5D=de&draft_pos%5B%5D=dl&draft_pos%5B%5D=ilb&draft_pos%5B%5D=olb&draft_pos%5B%5D=lb&draft_pos%5B%5D=cb&draft_pos%5B%5D=s&draft_pos%5B%5D=db&draft_pos%5B%5D=k&draft_pos%5B%5D=p&c1stat=pass_att&c1comp=gt&c1val=25&c5val=1.0&order_by=pass_td&offset=100', 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/play-index/psl_finder.cgi?request=1&match=combined&year_min=1920&year_max=2016&season_start=1&season_end=-1&pos%5B%5D=qb&pos%5B%5D=rb&pos%5B%5D=wr&pos%5B%5D=te&pos%5B%5D=e&pos%5B%5D=t&pos%5B%5D=g&pos%5B%5D=c&pos%5B%5D=ol&pos%5B%5D=dt&pos%5B%5D=de&pos%5B%5D=dl&pos%5B%5D=ilb&pos%5B%5D=olb&pos%5B%5D=lb&pos%5B%5D=cb&pos%5B%5D=s&pos%5B%5D=db&pos%5B%5D=k&pos%5B%5D=p&draft_year_min=1936&draft_year_max=2017&draft_slot_min=1&draft_slot_max=500&draft_pick_in_round=pick_overall&conference=any&draft_pos%5B%5D=qb&draft_pos%5B%5D=rb&draft_pos%5B%5D=wr&draft_pos%5B%5D=te&draft_pos%5B%5D=e&draft_pos%5B%5D=t&draft_pos%5B%5D=g&draft_pos%5B%5D=c&draft_pos%5B%5D=ol&draft_pos%5B%5D=dt&draft_pos%5B%5D=de&draft_pos%5B%5D=dl&draft_pos%5B%5D=ilb&draft_pos%5B%5D=olb&draft_pos%5B%5D=lb&draft_pos%5B%5D=cb&draft_pos%5B%5D=s&draft_pos%5B%5D=db&draft_pos%5B%5D=k&draft_pos%5B%5D=p&c1stat=pass_att&c1comp=gt&c1val=25&c5val=1.0&order_by=pass_td&offset=200', 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/play-index/psl_finder.cgi?request=1&match=combined&year_min=1920&year_max=2016&season_start=1&season_end=-1&pos%5B%5D=qb&pos%5B%5D=rb&pos%5B%5D=wr&pos%5B%5D=te&pos%5B%5D=e&pos%5B%5D=t&pos%5B%5D=g&pos%5B%5D=c&pos%5B%5D=ol&pos%5B%5D=dt&pos%5B%5D=de&pos%5B%5D=dl&pos%5B%5D=ilb&pos%5B%5D=olb&pos%5B%5D=lb&pos%5B%5D=cb&pos%5B%5D=s&pos%5B%5D=db&pos%5B%5D=k&pos%5B%5D=p&draft_year_min=1936&draft_year_max=2017&draft_slot_min=1&draft_slot_max=500&draft_pick_in_round=pick_overall&conference=any&draft_pos%5B%5D=qb&draft_pos%5B%5D=rb&draft_pos%5B%5D=wr&draft_pos%5B%5D=te&draft_pos%5B%5D=e&draft_pos%5B%5D=t&draft_pos%5B%5D=g&draft_pos%5B%5D=c&draft_pos%5B%5D=ol&draft_pos%5B%5D=dt&draft_pos%5B%5D=de&draft_pos%5B%5D=dl&draft_pos%5B%5D=ilb&draft_pos%5B%5D=olb&draft_pos%5B%5D=lb&draft_pos%5B%5D=cb&draft_pos%5B%5D=s&draft_pos%5B%5D=db&draft_pos%5B%5D=k&draft_pos%5B%5D=p&c1stat=pass_att&c1comp=gt&c1val=25&c5val=1.0&order_by=pass_td&offset=300', 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/play-index/psl_finder.cgi?request=1&match=combined&year_min=1920&year_max=2016&season_start=1&season_end=-1&pos%5B%5D=qb&pos%5B%5D=rb&pos%5B%5D=wr&pos%5B%5D=te&pos%5B%5D=e&pos%5B%5D=t&pos%5B%5D=g&pos%5B%5D=c&pos%5B%5D=ol&pos%5B%5D=dt&pos%5B%5D=de&pos%5B%5D=dl&pos%5B%5D=ilb&pos%5B%5D=olb&pos%5B%5D=lb&pos%5B%5D=cb&pos%5B%5D=s&pos%5B%5D=db&pos%5B%5D=k&pos%5B%5D=p&draft_year_min=1936&draft_year_max=2017&draft_slot_min=1&draft_slot_max=500&draft_pick_in_round=pick_overall&conference=any&draft_pos%5B%5D=qb&draft_pos%5B%5D=rb&draft_pos%5B%5D=wr&draft_pos%5B%5D=te&draft_pos%5B%5D=e&draft_pos%5B%5D=t&draft_pos%5B%5D=g&draft_pos%5B%5D=c&draft_pos%5B%5D=ol&draft_pos%5B%5D=dt&draft_pos%5B%5D=de&draft_pos%5B%5D=dl&draft_pos%5B%5D=ilb&draft_pos%5B%5D=olb&draft_pos%5B%5D=lb&draft_pos%5B%5D=cb&draft_pos%5B%5D=s&draft_pos%5B%5D=db&draft_pos%5B%5D=k&draft_pos%5B%5D=p&c1stat=pass_att&c1comp=gt&c1val=25&c5val=1.0&order_by=pass_td&offset=400', 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/play-index/psl_finder.cgi?request=1&match=combined&year_min=1920&year_max=2016&season_start=1&season_end=-1&pos%5B%5D=qb&pos%5B%5D=rb&pos%5B%5D=wr&pos%5B%5D=te&pos%5B%5D=e&pos%5B%5D=t&pos%5B%5D=g&pos%5B%5D=c&pos%5B%5D=ol&pos%5B%5D=dt&pos%5B%5D=de&pos%5B%5D=dl&pos%5B%5D=ilb&pos%5B%5D=olb&pos%5B%5D=lb&pos%5B%5D=cb&pos%5B%5D=s&pos%5B%5D=db&pos%5B%5D=k&pos%5B%5D=p&draft_year_min=1936&draft_year_max=2017&draft_slot_min=1&draft_slot_max=500&draft_pick_in_round=pick_overall&conference=any&draft_pos%5B%5D=qb&draft_pos%5B%5D=rb&draft_pos%5B%5D=wr&draft_pos%5B%5D=te&draft_pos%5B%5D=e&draft_pos%5B%5D=t&draft_pos%5B%5D=g&draft_pos%5B%5D=c&draft_pos%5B%5D=ol&draft_pos%5B%5D=dt&draft_pos%5B%5D=de&draft_pos%5B%5D=dl&draft_pos%5B%5D=ilb&draft_pos%5B%5D=olb&draft_pos%5B%5D=lb&draft_pos%5B%5D=cb&draft_pos%5B%5D=s&draft_pos%5B%5D=db&draft_pos%5B%5D=k&draft_pos%5B%5D=p&c1stat=pass_att&c1comp=gt&c1val=25&c5val=1.0&order_by=pass_td&offset=500', 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/play-index/psl_finder.cgi?request=1&match=combined&year_min=1920&year_max=2016&season_start=1&season_end=-1&pos%5B%5D=qb&pos%5B%5D=rb&pos%5B%5D=wr&pos%5B%5D=te&pos%5B%5D=e&pos%5B%5D=t&pos%5B%5D=g&pos%5B%5D=c&pos%5B%5D=ol&pos%5B%5D=dt&pos%5B%5D=de&pos%5B%5D=dl&pos%5B%5D=ilb&pos%5B%5D=olb&pos%5B%5D=lb&pos%5B%5D=cb&pos%5B%5D=s&pos%5B%5D=db&pos%5B%5D=k&pos%5B%5D=p&draft_year_min=1936&draft_year_max=2017&draft_slot_min=1&draft_slot_max=500&draft_pick_in_round=pick_overall&conference=any&draft_pos%5B%5D=qb&draft_pos%5B%5D=rb&draft_pos%5B%5D=wr&draft_pos%5B%5D=te&draft_pos%5B%5D=e&draft_pos%5B%5D=t&draft_pos%5B%5D=g&draft_pos%5B%5D=c&draft_pos%5B%5D=ol&draft_pos%5B%5D=dt&draft_pos%5B%5D=de&draft_pos%5B%5D=dl&draft_pos%5B%5D=ilb&draft_pos%5B%5D=olb&draft_pos%5B%5D=lb&draft_pos%5B%5D=cb&draft_pos%5B%5D=s&draft_pos%5B%5D=db&draft_pos%5B%5D=k&draft_pos%5B%5D=p&c1stat=pass_att&c1comp=gt&c1val=25&c5val=1.0&order_by=pass_td&offset=600', 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/play-index/psl_finder.cgi?request=1&match=combined&year_min=1920&year_max=2016&season_start=1&season_end=-1&pos%5B%5D=qb&pos%5B%5D=rb&pos%5B%5D=wr&pos%5B%5D=te&pos%5B%5D=e&pos%5B%5D=t&pos%5B%5D=g&pos%5B%5D=c&pos%5B%5D=ol&pos%5B%5D=dt&pos%5B%5D=de&pos%5B%5D=dl&pos%5B%5D=ilb&pos%5B%5D=olb&pos%5B%5D=lb&pos%5B%5D=cb&pos%5B%5D=s&pos%5B%5D=db&pos%5B%5D=k&pos%5B%5D=p&draft_year_min=1936&draft_year_max=2017&draft_slot_min=1&draft_slot_max=500&draft_pick_in_round=pick_overall&conference=any&draft_pos%5B%5D=qb&draft_pos%5B%5D=rb&draft_pos%5B%5D=wr&draft_pos%5B%5D=te&draft_pos%5B%5D=e&draft_pos%5B%5D=t&draft_pos%5B%5D=g&draft_pos%5B%5D=c&draft_pos%5B%5D=ol&draft_pos%5B%5D=dt&draft_pos%5B%5D=de&draft_pos%5B%5D=dl&draft_pos%5B%5D=ilb&draft_pos%5B%5D=olb&draft_pos%5B%5D=lb&draft_pos%5B%5D=cb&draft_pos%5B%5D=s&draft_pos%5B%5D=db&draft_pos%5B%5D=k&draft_pos%5B%5D=p&c1stat=pass_att&c1comp=gt&c1val=25&c5val=1.0&order_by=pass_td&offset=700', 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/play-index/psl_finder.cgi?request=1&match=combined&year_min=1920&year_max=2016&season_start=1&season_end=-1&pos%5B%5D=qb&pos%5B%5D=rb&pos%5B%5D=wr&pos%5B%5D=te&pos%5B%5D=e&pos%5B%5D=t&pos%5B%5D=g&pos%5B%5D=c&pos%5B%5D=ol&pos%5B%5D=dt&pos%5B%5D=de&pos%5B%5D=dl&pos%5B%5D=ilb&pos%5B%5D=olb&pos%5B%5D=lb&pos%5B%5D=cb&pos%5B%5D=s&pos%5B%5D=db&pos%5B%5D=k&pos%5B%5D=p&draft_year_min=1936&draft_year_max=2017&draft_slot_min=1&draft_slot_max=500&draft_pick_in_round=pick_overall&conference=any&draft_pos%5B%5D=qb&draft_pos%5B%5D=rb&draft_pos%5B%5D=wr&draft_pos%5B%5D=te&draft_pos%5B%5D=e&draft_pos%5B%5D=t&draft_pos%5B%5D=g&draft_pos%5B%5D=c&draft_pos%5B%5D=ol&draft_pos%5B%5D=dt&draft_pos%5B%5D=de&draft_pos%5B%5D=dl&draft_pos%5B%5D=ilb&draft_pos%5B%5D=olb&draft_pos%5B%5D=lb&draft_pos%5B%5D=cb&draft_pos%5B%5D=s&draft_pos%5B%5D=db&draft_pos%5B%5D=k&draft_pos%5B%5D=p&c1stat=pass_att&c1comp=gt&c1val=25&c5val=1.0&order_by=pass_td&offset=800']
```

Or, more concisely:

```
list of urls = ['&offset=0', '&offset=100', '&offset=200', '&offset=300', '&offset=400', '&offset=500', '&offset=600', '&offset700', '&offset=800']
```

The following is what I have so far for my attempt at creating the function. My approach is to try to iterate through the urls and check if there is a table on the url or not. The idea is that "if" there is a table on the page, append the url to my output list, and if there is not a table on the page, exit the function. But this only produces a list of the first two urls -- it's not looping back to append the last 7 urls for the list.

```
def get_url_list(frontpage_url):
    offset_extension = ''
    output_list = [frontpage_url]
    x = 0

    for url in output_list:
        results_table = pd.read_html(url)
        table_results = pd.DataFrame(results_table)

        if table_results.empty == False:
            x+=1
            offset_extension = '&offset=' + '%d' % (100 * x)
            output_list.append(frontpage_url + offset_extension)

        else:
            exit
    return output_list[1:-1]
```

urls_list_output = get_url_list(sports_url_starter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach looks okay but your `for` loop is incorrect. When using `for` you don't need to index into the list you are looping through, ie you shouldn't use `output_list[x]`.

Try replacing it with something like:

```
results = []
for url in output_list:
    try:
        # read_html returns a list of dataframes, so add all to the results
        results.extend(pd.read_html(url))
        ...
        output_list.append(new_url)
    except ValueError:
        # if there are no tables on the page return what you have so far
        return results
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed my code to reflect your suggestions but I'm still not getting it to work. This just produces: "ValueError: No tables found"  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you happen to see why my function wouldn't be working now?  @dugup

Comment: I imagine the `ValueError` occurs when pandas is trying to read the html, you could try wrapping the calls in a try except block. You may also want to build up a list of the dataframes as you go along and return that instead of the list of urls?  I've updated the answer, good luck!

Comment: Yeah, this works, thanks. Is it considered bad practice to use errors as a way of ending functions like this if you want the function to be useful for repeat purposes?

Comment: You're welcome :) Using try-catch blocks in python is actually promoted (rather than testing the results with if), check out https://docs.python.org/3.6/glossary.html#term-eafp. `ValueError` is one of the possible outputs of the pandas method you are calling, so catching in the function you call it in shouldn't affect the reusability